# jquery set the text option list generate by php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

why the jquery contains doesn't select the specific value to where i want to select when i load the page.

```
<select class="form-control" style="width:120px; float:left;" name="namelist">
    <option value="">Pablo I</option>
    <option value="">Pablo II</option>
    <option value="">Pablo III</option>
    <option value="">Pablo IV</option>
</select>

<script>               
    $('select[name=namelist] option:contains("Pablo II")').attr('selected','selected');
</script>
```

the result selected is Pablo III

Comment: `Pablo III` contains `Pablo II` so at a guess its selecting the last of the 2 matches

Comment: manual for option:contains says *Select all elements that contain the specified text.* since they both do i would guess both are being set to selected; but that is only valid for one, so the browser is using the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) because [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) will return partial matches also

```js
$('select[name=namelist] option').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == 'Pablo II'
}).attr('selected','selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" style="width:120px; float:left;" name="namelist">
    <option value="">Pablo I</option>
    <option value="">Pablo II</option>
    <option value="">Pablo III</option>
    <option value="">Pablo IV</option>
</select>
```

Comment: could he just specify a value for the option's and make this a lot easier ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Prop() works well too
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```js
$('select[name=namelist] option').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == 'Pablo II'
}).prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" style="width:120px; float:left;" name="namelist">
    <option value="">Pablo I</option>
    <option value="">Pablo II</option>
    <option value="">Pablo III</option>
    <option value="">Pablo IV</option>
</select>
```